atmosic atm2202. send picture to eink
I have a "eink electronic shelf label". I know that the heart of the device is the Atmosic atm2202. Also, I know that the device works via BLE. I would like to create an image and send it to the device, but my attempts are not successful.
Yes, I can use the E-label application, but I would like to use something third-party.
How to deal with such devices correctly? Please share examples.
Here's what I did.
python code for search the device:
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

asyncio.run(main())

after all, work via Fedora 39 bluetooth console application:
scan le
pair <MAC_ADDRESS>
connect  <MAC_ADDRESS>
advertize on
advertise on
gatt.list-attributes

and some tries:
gatt.select-attribute 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
write "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x19 0xff"
gatt.select-attribute 00001526-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
write "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x19 0xff"
gatt.select-attribute 00001523-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
write "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x19 0xff"
gatt.select-attribute 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
gatt.select-attribute 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
write "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x19 0xff"
gatt.select-attribute 00001525-1212-efde-1523-785feabcd123
write "0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x19 0xff"

I hope I haven't infringed on anyone's copyrights.

Without the documentation your only options are basically to either search for a library by product name, trying to find a solution by trial-and-error (maybe using a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect) or trying to sniff the communication between the device and the official app
